# List(array) of HTML element with django 2.0.6

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm passing a list of HTML element to the views.py from html through post but Im just getting the last value.

here is the html code that i used, multiple lines of this one

```
<input name="idborrow[]" id="borrow" value='+element[i].id+'>
```

and here is my code in the views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    idborrow = request.POST.get('idborrow[]', '')

    print (idborrow)
```

in the console, it just prints the last value, how to get the whole list of values

Comment: `request.POST.getlist('idborrow[]')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **[getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)**

**Ex:**

```
request.POST.getlist('idborrow[]')
```